# Use SQL queries virtual console to do any thing on a SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server

How can I use a rich textbox and some pre-connected string to execute direct Transact-SQL queries and get results into a datagridview?

My GUI form is like this:

[image]

I want to use any SQL queries in this rich textbox and get result in data grid view

I using this code for query and fill data gridview

```
SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=db3;Integrated Security=True");

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from phone", c);
        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        a.Fill(t);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
}
```

So how do I modify it to this?

```
SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=db3;Integrated Security=True");

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(Textbox1.Text, c);
        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        a.Fill(t);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
}
```

I also used Pravin Deshmukh code in another button and get error:

Update 3: used suggested code and got a reference error

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            string SqlString = textBox2.Text; // here you can have your user query from textbox
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=db3;Integrated Security=True"].ConnectionString.ToString());
            conn.Open();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlString, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            da.Fill(ds);

            conn.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
}
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: That is such a bad idea (from security perspective). Just give the user SQL Management Studio? Otherwise, you can use normal ADO.Net to perform a query, and examine the result to determine the grid layout from the `DataTable`(s) returned. Bear in mind that the user might type two queries, which would require two grids. SSMS manages this and many other aspects better than you will.

Comment: its not client side its admin form and i don't want to go and execute  sql cmd from sql management studio  i want to use a textbox or rich textbox execute from c# form

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string SqlString= "your sql query";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=db3;Integrated Security=True");
conn.Open();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlString, conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);


da.Fill(ds);

conn.Close();
cmd.Dispose();
```

Set datagridview generate columns automatic

**EDIT :** or

```
string SqlString= textbox1.Text; // here you can have your user query from textbox
```

Comment: i like your code bro  specially  line 6 but  what is the  first line for???   using a query for what??  i want to get query from textbox or rich textbox  not a static query

Comment: thanks for answers i edit my post and  try using your code inside my code plz check  its ok or not

Comment: i used your code but getting error -    Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: For which line you are getting this ? remember to replace `textbox1.Text` with your richtextbox id . text

Comment: for this line: SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString());

Comment: Ohh you need to use your connection string to sql there or add ConnectionString in web.config

Comment: 1- used code and screenshot updated    2- but my project hasn't a web.config it have a  app.config

Comment: Ok, i have updated code in my answer to match with your sql connection, do check